# Ideal Virtual Machine configuration for Micro Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Could you please suggest an ideal VM configuration for using micro cloud foundry. I understand that the configuration could depend on a lot of parameters but I am looking for something that allows smooth operations without making the guest or host machine too slow in terms of performance.

Comment: You realize Micro Cloud Foundry is suitable only for development, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you download Micro Cloud, It already comes in a configured VM. You can review the VM configurations but there is no need for you to manually create a new VM.

The "micro.vmx" is the VM.

Here is the link to the docs about Micro Cloud for more information:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/micro/installing-mcf.html